# Got an error when installing an extension for Eclipse

Tags: php, angularjs, eclipse

I am trying to install the AngularJS extension for Eclipse IDE ( Helios Release for PHP developers) but I keep receiving the following error message :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: AngularJS support for PHP (PDT) 1.1.0.201511091212 (angularjs-eclipse-php-feature.feature.group 1.1.0.201511091212)
  Missing requirement: Tern - Eclipse 1.1.0.201511082254 (tern.eclipse 1.1.0.201511082254) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AngularJS support for PHP (PDT) 1.1.0.201511091212 (angularjs-eclipse-php-feature.feature.group 1.1.0.201511091212)
    To: org.eclipse.angularjs.php.core [1.1.0.201511091212]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse AngularJS PHP - Core 1.1.0.201511091212 (org.eclipse.angularjs.php.core 1.1.0.201511091212)
    To: bundle tern.eclipse 0.0.0
```

What should I do ? I am new to using eclipse

Comment: Your problem is because you are using a very old version of Eclipse (it's the problem with requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0'). Helios was available in 2010. So I suggest you that you download Eclipse JEE Distribution Mars version (2015)

Answer (score 1):

check your current installation of `org.eclipse.swt` plugin by `(eclipse menu) > Help > Installation Details > (select) Plugins (tab) > (search for) org.eclipse.swt > (look at) Version`.

if the plugin does not exists or version is different/smaller then you need to install/update `org.eclipse.swt` plugin first.

By the way, `Helios` is too old. it is now `Mars`, so try getting last version of eclipse and I think you will not face that problem.